# PHP find dependencies of multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am able to traverse a multi-dimensional array, but I also need information about dependencies. Here is what I am trying to do. I have an array like this:

```
array(
    'top1' => 'sth',
    'top2' => array(
        'sub1' => 'sth',
        'sub2' => array(
            'line1' => 'sth',
            'line2' => 'sth'
        )
    )
    'top3' => 'sth'
)
```

I am able to traverse the array to get all the keys, result is this:

```
array([0] => 'top1', [1] => 'top2', [2] => 'sub1', [3] => 'sub2', ...)
```

However, I need to know the parent of the current element. So I hope I could get something like this:

```
array(
    [top1] => array('parent' => 0, 'id' => 1),
    [top2] => array('parent' => 0, 'id' => 2),
    [sub1] => array('parent' => 2, 'id' => 2.1),
    [sub2] => array('parent' => 2, 'id' => 2.2),
    [line1] => array('parent' => 2.2, 'id' => 2.2.1),
    ...
    [top3] => array('parent' => 0, 'id' => 3)
)
```

I have been trying many ways, but couldn't always  get the correct result. Can anyone solve this out? Thanks!

Comment: What is your code to get the flat array?

Answer (score 1):

here is a working example for you

```
function traverse(array $input, $parent = null) {

    $result = array();
    $current = 1;
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

        $id = null !== $parent ? $parent . '.' . $current : $current;
        $result[$key] = array('parent' => null !== $parent ? $parent : 0, 'id' => $id);
        if (is_array($value)) {

            $result = array_merge($result, traverse($value, $id));
        }

        $current++;
    }

    return $result;
}

$input = array(
    'top1' => 'sth',
    'top2' => array(
        'sub1' => 'sth',
        'sub2' => array(
            'line1' => 'sth',
            'line2' => 'sth'
        )
    ),
    'top3' => 'sth'
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($input);
echo '<hr>';
print_r(traverse($input));
echo '</pre>';
```